# JNLP doesn't show splash screen when launching from a desktop icon

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have been able to create a JNLP file, which successfully sets up a splash screen & a desktop icon for a Java program launched through Web Start. Here's the relevant chunk of the JNLP:

Now, to launch the program, I find I can either click on the JNLP, in which case the splash screen shows, or on the desktop icon, in which case the default Java Web Start splash screen shows instead. This is on Windows XP & Windows Vista, and it's Java 1.5 and Java 1.6.

Is there a way to get my splash screen to show when launching from the JNLP file, instead of the Java one?

Thanks.

Comment: Now been able to test it with Ubuntu and Java 1.6, and the results are the same. Beginning to look like it's supposed to be that way, but is it? That you can't have your splash screen if you launch from your desktop icon?

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the most recent minor upgrade of Java 6 seems to have fixed this, at least on the Windows platforms. So I am now on update 16. I was on 9 before I think, and this has been fixed somewhere along the line.

First thing I should have tried? Probably!